# Android TextView in RelativeLayout wrapping

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to make a relativeLayout with three textViews in a column on the left and two buttons next to each other on the right. The problem is, when the first textView is short "i.e. 3 or 4 characters" the textViews below get wrapped whenever they are longer then the first textView. I don't want this and want them to go all the way to the buttons if possible. I know I'm probably missing a parameter or something similar. Can anybody help me?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_class1" android:visibility="visible">


<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/TextView_class1_name" android:textColor="@color/Button_Text1"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_class1_name" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView_class1_name" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView_class1_name" android:id="@+id/TextView_class1_building" android:textColor="@color/Button_Text1">    </TextView>
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_class1_building" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView_class1_building" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView_class1_building" android:id="@+id/TextView_class1_room" android:textColor="@color/Button_Text1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:width="0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
<Button android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button_class1_map" android:minHeight="@dimen/button_small_size" android:minWidth="@dimen/button_small_size" android:maxHeight="@dimen/button_small_size" android:maxWidth="@dimen/button_small_size" android:text="@string/text_map" android:layout_centerVertical="true"></Button>
<Button android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button_class1_map" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button_class1_map" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button_class1_map" android:id="@+id/Button_class1_edit" android:minHeight="@dimen/button_small_size" android:minWidth="@dimen/button_small_size" android:maxHeight="@dimen/button_small_size" android:maxWidth="@dimen/button_small_size" android:text="@string/text_edit" android:layout_centerVertical="true"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a table layout? It might be a little easier to design because you are talking about columns and rows. The problem with relative is that its going to change based on the others, if you don't want this to happen then using a table layout with x rows and y columns will be a lot easier.

Along with this, using table layout allows you to specific zeroing-in in a particular column or having a particular element consume more than one column.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced something similar when creating a home screen widget. As widgets have limited options, a TableLayout could not be used. I reverted to something that translates as follows to your situation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_class1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="short" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="shrt" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_class1_room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="quite a bit longer" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 2" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```